# Can I enter a Schengen country early as a visa-free traveler, then a week later begin staying with my Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, visa-free-entry, transition-of-visa-status

So I have a passport that is visa free in Schengen, but I received a year long visa for France. I just found out a friend is getting married before the start of the visa and want to attend obviously. Can I just enter as a "tourist", then slide into the start of the long stay visa? Or would I have to leave and come back?

(I saw dupes of this question but they are from people who don't have visa-free travel in the Schengen zone)

Comment: I don't think it makes a huge difference in practice but will you enter the Schengen area through France or stay in another country before moving to France? Have you secured accommodation in France?

Comment: I will most likely enter through france. I don't have accomodation set up yet

Comment: Regarding related questions: almost everything that applies to entry on a short-stay Schengen visa also applies to visa-free entry (even if in practice scrutiny is much more limited). See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area or https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-long-term-visa-ends-in-schengen-countr (same combination but starting with the long-stay visa).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch from Tourist visa to Resident visa status in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88153/how-to-switch-from-tourist-visa-to-resident-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Another relevant question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/accepted-student-with-long-sejour-visa-ofii-to-france-but-arriving-as-tourist

Answer (score 4):

Official answer from the Consulate in DC

> Dear Sir,
>
> You can enter before on your 90/180 days allowance BUT
>
> <<Or would I need to leave the schengen area and re-enter to get a valid stamp matching the visa start date?>>
>
> You will have to leave the Schengen area (visiting UK for example) to have your long-stay Visa activated.

Answer (score 2):

French long-stay visas typically need to be validated within three months of entering France (there are exceptions, including working holiday visas). This used to entail a medical checkup and getting a sticker but [can now be done online](https://administration-etrangers-en-france.interieur.gouv.fr/particuliers/#/). What happens if you exceed that delay is not completely clear. In theory your presence could be deemed illegal which would in turn create many problems down the line but I have also heard of people who submitted their application a little late and didn't suffer any consequences.

Note that this is three months after entering France, not the Schengen area. A long visa-free visit elsewhere in the Schengen area before could therefore create some difficulties because it would prevent you to use your entry stamp to document your date of entry or could make it appear as if you went past the three-month deadline. A week is not long enough to be a problem.

Comment: My visa is working holiday, so no need to validate anything I think. But good information to know thank you! I will call the consulate directly to clear this up